# setbackground color for week day in Android app

Tags: android, listview, background-color, weekday

I am developing a week data application in Android. I would like to set the **background color** for weekday (example: friday). I am using the **listview** in xml.  Thanks a lot for your suggestions,

```
 private void addDateView(LinearLayout layout, String text,
        boolean isCurrentDay) {
    listview child = new listview(layout.getContext());



    if (isCurrentDay) {
        child.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(242, 199, 125));
    } else {
        child.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
    }

    child.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
    child.setTextColor(Color.RED);
    [enter image description here][1]child.setPadding(8, 8, 8, 8);
    layout.addView(child, (SCREEN_WIDTH / 7), 50);
}
```

Comment: what's the problem with this code? It look ok

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I am getting errors with boolean and int. I don't know how to figure out. If you have any code or links that would be great. thanks a lot!

Comment: add the full error message to the question, and indicate the lines in your code that appear in the error log

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the day do the following :

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
int day = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
```

To set the background according to the day :

```
switch (day) {
case Calendar.SUNDAY:


case Calendar.MONDAY:

}
```

And So on, inside the case put your changing logic .